# When calling SharePoint REST OData api, what is the biggest value allowed by $top?

Tags: rest, odata

I am making calls to get all sub-sites of a site collection using:

`${siteCollectionUrl}/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos`

But there are 1000's of them. So I need to get them in pages using the `$top` and `$skip` parameters.

For example here would be the 5th page of 100 row pages:

`${siteCollectionUrl}/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos?$top=100&$skip=500`

What is the biggest value I can use as `$top`? Is the limit 500? Is that limit configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its limit is 5000. If you want to have more than that you can utilize batching or make multiple calls or paging.

Comment: Just checking - you said "I think"... Are you able to verify that answer? Thanks.